# in Firebase DB get children value by ordering childByValue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Firebase database managing following structure.

```
-DATA
    -New
        -CONTENTS
            -animals_animal1: 1
            -foods_food10: 4
            -foods_food6: 5
            -girls_girl1: 2
            -girls_girl5: 3
```

I want to get children's value by using orderByValue() as `1,2,3,4,5` manner using `snaps.forEach` in JavaScript. My code as follows.

```
exports.handleAddNewContentAndAddToNewEvent = functions.database.ref('/CONTENT_MANAGEMENT/DATA/CONTENTS/{contentId}')
    .onWrite(event => {

      // Only edit data when it is first created.
      if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
        return;
      }
      // Exit when the data is deleted.
      if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return;
      }
var newContentsRef = event.data.ref.parent.parent.child('PACKS/New/CONTENTS');


    return Promise.all([
       newContentsRef.orderByValue().once('value')
       ]).then(function(snaps) {
          snaps.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log('loaded', childKey);
            // ...
          });
    }); 
});
```

However, I failed to get intended solution. How to get solution what I need?

Structure
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy ?

Comment: Can you add the console result ? Did you add .index: "value" in your rules ?

Comment: @Pipiks `loaded CONTENTS`. This is cloud function.

Comment: Please add the path for your firebase cloud function trigger.

Comment: @Pipiks `exports.handleAddNewContentAndAddToNewEvent = functions.database.ref('/CONTENT_MANAGEMENT/DATA/CONTENTS/{contentId}')`

Comment: And what is the trigger ? (onWrite, onCreate...) please update your question with the code and the full structure.

Comment: @Pipiks I have updated my code.

Comment: Your structure doesn't contain CONTENT_MANAGEMENT or PACKS please add the full structure or explain what do you want exactly

Comment: I have updated my question with DB structure.

Comment: And the console print only `loaded CONTENTS` ? Try to print childData